# Tracking multiple objects in iOS 13

Tags: ios13, vision, video-tracking

my app uses the example code by Apple to track multiple objects of a video using Vision (in my case, it tracks the path of a barbell during weightlifting exercises), but after updating to iOS 13 the video is not displayed properly. Instead of filling the screen like it used to do, now the video is cropped and you can only see a small portion of it. I've talked to Apple Technical support and they acknowledge the bug, but a fix is not in their plans.

What bugs me the most is that a) landscape videos are working, but not portrait videos and b) the bug only happens in real devices and not in the simulator. See attached the portion of the code used to display the video depending on its proportions (landscape or portrait).

```
private func scaleImage(to viewSize: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
    guard self.image != nil && self.image.size != CGSize.zero else {
        return nil
    }

    self.imageAreaRect = CGRect.zero

    // There are two possible cases to fully fit self.image into the the ImageTrackingView area:
    // Option 1) image.width = view.width ==> image.height <= view.height
    // Option 2) image.height = view.height ==> image.width <= view.width
    let imageAspectRatio = self.image.size.width / self.image.size.height

    // Check if we're in Option 1) case and initialize self.imageAreaRect accordingly
    let imageSizeOption1 = CGSize(width: viewSize.width, height: floor(viewSize.width / imageAspectRatio))
    if imageSizeOption1.height <= viewSize.height {

        print("Landscape. View size: \(viewSize)")
        let imageX: CGFloat = 0
        let imageY = floor((viewSize.height - imageSizeOption1.height) / 2.0)
        self.imageAreaRect = CGRect(x: imageX,
                                    y: imageY,
                                    width: imageSizeOption1.width,
                                    height: imageSizeOption1.height)

    }

    if self.imageAreaRect == CGRect.zero {
        // Check if we're in Option 2) case if Option 1) didn't work out and initialize imageAreaRect accordingly

        print("portrait. View size: \(viewSize)")
        let imageSizeOption2 = CGSize(width: floor(viewSize.height * imageAspectRatio), height: viewSize.height)
        if imageSizeOption2.width <= viewSize.width {

            let imageX = floor((viewSize.width - imageSizeOption2.width) / 2.0)
            let imageY: CGFloat = 0
            self.imageAreaRect = CGRect(x: imageX,
                                        y: imageY,
                                        width: imageSizeOption2.width,
                                        height: imageSizeOption2.height)

        }
    }

    // In next line, pass 0.0 to use the current device's pixel scaling factor (and thus account for Retina resolution).
    // Pass 1.0 to force exact pixel size.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.imageAreaRect.size, false, 0.0)
    self.image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.imageAreaRect.size.width, height: self.imageAreaRect.size.height))

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage
}
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: As a side note, I found that the Object tracking feature in iOS 13 is almost broken... it barely works. For a feature I've implemented in iOS 12 I was getting tracking confidence of 0.8-0.99 constantly, where on iOS 13 the confidence never goes above 0.15.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Andy. I didn't experience that issue: my app basically tracks everything as it used to do. If you are using Apple's sample code as I do, have you tried the workaround I provided in my self-answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after several weeks stalking Apple Technical Support, they came out with a very simple workaround. Basically, you just need to do a conversion via CGImage instead of going directly from CIImage to UIImage.

This is the old code (as you can see in current example in Apple's documentation)

```
 if let frame = frame {
            let ciImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: frame).transformed(by: transform)
            let uiImage = UIImage(ciImage: ciImage)
            self.trackingView.image = uiImage
        }
```

And this is the correction

```
if let frame = frame {
            let ciImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: frame).transformed(by: transform)
            guard let cgImage = CIContext.init().createCGImage(ciImage, from: ciImage.extent) else {
                return
            }
            let uiImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
            self.trackingView.image = uiImage
        }
```

Hope this helps!